# I get an EOF error when running my code, what can i do?

Tags: python, eof

Basically i have a programm in which you must set the teachers patience and then count "one", "two", "three", "four", "one" and etc and when you fail it write "the streak was ... , but you failed" and after the patience reaches 0 the teacher says "enough for today" and ignores all inputs afterwards, but when i get an order like this:

```
2
one
two
three
four
one
twu
one
two
three
three
```

in some cases i get EOF error when launching it, even though i converted all needed inputs in ints.
code:

```
patience = int(input())
a = input()
streak = 0
mistake = False
one = "one"
two = "two"
three = "three"
four = "four"
nextNum = one
while 1:
    if a == nextNum:
        mistake = False
        streak += 1
        if nextNum == one:
            nextNum = two
        elif nextNum == two:
            nextNum = three
        elif nextNum == three:
            nextNum = four
        elif nextNum == four:
            nextNum = one
    elif not mistake:
        mistake = True
        nextNum = one
        patience -= 1
        if patience == 0:
            print("The counting streak was " + str(streak) + ", but you failed.")
            print("Enough for today.")
        if patience >= 1:
            print("The counting streak was " + str(streak) + ", but you failed.")
        streak = 0
    a = input()
```

I dunno what's the problem here because its like a random chance and i don't get why.

Comment: Try your code using `https://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit` and you'll see what happens as you step through.

Comment: how much patience does each teacher start with ?

Answer (score 0):

**Reason**

Lets look at the `while` loop, when you first guess it right, the variable `mistake` is set to `false`. so if you guess wrong on the second time around the `mistake` is set to `true`. On the third time around if you guess wrong again nothing will happen. cause `nextNum` is **not equal** to variable `a`, and `mistake` was set to `True` earlier. Therefore instead of using `elif` use `else`. this way, if the `nextNum` is not guessed correctly, the else case runs.

**Solution**

I suggest changing the `elif not mistake:` to `else:`.
Also don't forget to remove the other three reference for the boolean variable of `mistake =`, its just an unnecessary line.